# What is my true color?

Tags: riddle

> When I am white, I do good.
>   When I am black, I do evil.
>   When I am grey, I do both.
>   When I am red, I rule.

What am I?

Comment: cant stop thinking of Signal ;)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

you are

> a hat !

When I am white, I do good.

> white hats hacks for the common good, to help improve network security

When I am black, I do evil.

> black hats hacks for fun and profit

When I am grey, I do both.

> a gray hat hacks sometime for the common good, and sometime for despicable reasons

When I am red, I rule.

> red hat is a widely used, and rather good, linux distribution (probably leader on the market)

Comment: That was too easy :)

Answer (score 10):

Another answer that works is

> the Four Horsemen of the Apocalypse.

*When I am white, I do good.*

> The rider of the white horse is sometimes said to represent Jesus.

*When I am black, I do evil.*

> The rider of the black horse usually represents famine, which is an evil outcome.

*When I am grey, I do both.*

> The rider of the grey horse represents death, which is often an evil thing but can sometimes be merciful and a relief.

*When I am red, I rule.*

> The rider of the red horse represents war: a conflict often fought to decide who should rule.

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_Horsemen_of_the_Apocalypse).

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I learned something reading it. +1

Comment: _"which is undoubtedly an evil phenomenon"_ I don't think you can realistically claim that famine is "undoubtedly" evil. You'd have to demonstrate that famine has malicious intent, for starters.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Hey, it's a riddle - allusion, caricaturising, and personification are fine! Is it better after my edit?

Comment: Probably.​​​​​​